# Access violation and strange behavior of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory-management, memory-leaks, directx, directx-11

I'm writing a test application on DirectX11, and I have 2 classes "Box" and "camera" . "Box" is a cube which is to be drawn on the screen, and this is "camera":

```
class camera 
{ 
public :
const camera operator=(const camera& fv) const
{
    return fv;
}
XMVECTOR eye;
XMVECTOR at;
XMVECTOR up;
XMVECTOR right;
XMVECTOR left;
XMVECTOR down;
float pitch; //x
float roll; //z
float yaw; //y

XMMATRIX View;
XMMATRIX Projection;
camera();
camera(XMVECTOR eye, XMVECTOR at, XMVECTOR up, float movingOffset, float radius);
void Move(XMVECTOR Offset);
void MoveCameraRight(float offset);
void Rotate(XMVECTOR offset);
void MoveCameraLeft(float offset);

void MoveCameraUp(float offset);
void MoveCameraDown(float offset);
void MoveCameraCloser(float offset);
} ;
```

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012, and all was perfect, until I decided to build my solution under Release config. Camera constructor has always fallen on **"Unhandled exception: Acces violation reading location..."** on different addresses near 0x0. I know why it's happening, I've checked all of the pointers I've used, and I completely don't understand, what is happening. Here is the beginning of the file with the WinMain function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DIMouse.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


HINSTANCE               g_hInst = nullptr;
HWND                    g_hWnd = nullptr;
HRESULT                 hr = S_OK;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         g_driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pImmediateContext = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = nullptr;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = nullptr;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader = nullptr;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader = nullptr;
ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pConstantBuffer = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pIndexBuffer = nullptr;
XMMATRIX                g_World;                     // World matrix
XMMATRIX                g_View;           // View matrix
XMMATRIX                g_Projection;           // Projection matrix

int BOXES_COUNT = 50;
int Radius = 20;
FILE* fpsLog = NULL;
Box** boxes;
camera* cam;
FPS fps;
int calculationId = 0;

 HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
 HRESULT InitDevice();
 HRESULT InitGeometry();
 void parseArgs(LPWSTR  lpl);
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
void Render();
HRESULT InitCamera();   
void InitCubes(int boxesCount);
cDIObject DIObject;
cMouse Mouse;

 int WINAPI wWinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,   _In_     LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow )
 {
//parse args
parseArgs( lpCmdLine );
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

  ....
     if (FAILED ( InitCamera()))
{
    .....
```

InitCamera() - a function, where I call the constructor, when all crashes:

```
HRESULT InitCamera()
{
  RECT rc;
   GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
   UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;           
   UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;   
   g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();

   XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, -45, 0.0f );  
   XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );    
   XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );    
   g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH( Eye, At, Up );
   g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( XM_PIDIV4, width / (FLOAT)height, 0.01f,    100.0f );
cam = (camera*)malloc(sizeof(camera));
  camera * c = new camera( Eye, At, Up, 0.5, Radius );
cam = c;
```

*cam* is a global pointer to camera class, don't look at me that way, this worked under VS for some time.

If I need to parse command line arguments, which are taken from lpCmdLine, I need to alloc memory, and  I've thought, that the reason were memory allocations in the beginning of ..Main. I used *malloc()* and arrays ( with new and then delete ), but even if I'd called free() and used the delete operator, "access violation" also  happened. But , now attention! Sometimes it worked under Visual Studio, when I hadn't tried to alloc memory, and didn't worked , when I just launched an .exe file. Then I decided to check out what would happen without memory allocations, and it worked under VS and outside ( when I launched the .exe ). But when I removed all mem allocations from code to see what would happen, I also got "Access violation..." on the line

```
   camera * c = new camera( Eye, At, Up, 0.5, Radius );
```

I have working solution under the Debug mode, and I decided to disable optimisations under Release, it worked under VS than and didn't work when I launched the .exe. I've tried everything and I don't know how to deal with this case. I've checked out again, I have no bad pointers. I've read something about memory leaks, but even if I 'd tried to *delete* or *free()* memory after my usage, it crashed anyway. I'm desperate.

Comment: Almost certainly due to `XMMATRIX` member variables not being 16-byte aligned.

Comment: I have 16-byte structure member alignment in the project properties...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already checked and debugged all possible pointer issues (I have a doubt), the most probable bug is unaligned DirectXMath. [`XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX` objects must be 16-byte aligned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Properly_Align_Alloc).

Possible solutions are:

- Use aligned allocations
- Do not use dynamic allocation (place objects on stack)
- Use `XMFLOATa` and `XMFLOATaXb` (where `a` and `b` are dimensions) as storage (class members, function parameters, etc.) and convert to `XMMATRIX` and `XMVECTOR` (placed on ctack) just before calculations
- Disable SSE intrinsics (put [`#define _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before include file). It will disable alignment requirement
- Do not use DirectXMath (there are plenty other math libraries)

Probably you will find this two answers useful: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391389/1607442), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18711837/1607442)

<sup>**C++ notes** (offtopic):

 - Never mix `new`/`free`, `malloc`/`delete`. You can not.

 - We tend to avoid all four of this in C++. Prefer to use smart pointers: `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, and their companion functions: `std::make_shared`, `std::make_unique()`

 - This is a memory leak (memory allocated for `cam` is lost forever after assignment and you cannot release it anymore):</sup>

```
cam = (camera*)malloc(sizeof(camera));
camera * c = new camera( Eye, At, Up, 0.5, Radius );
cam = c;
```

<sup>- Do instead:</sup>

```
std::shared_ptr<Camera> cam;
...
cam = std::make_shared<Camera>(Eye, At, Up, 0.5, Radius);
```

<sup>- Global variables considered evil in C++</sup>
<sup>- Raw pointers considered evil in C++</sup>
 <sup>- Check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) ("Best Practices" and "Intermediate" sections)</sup>

Hope it helps somehow.
Happy coding!

Comment: It seems like I've finally fixed the bug. What I've done:

1. I've stopped to use dynamic allocations.
2. I've started to use XMFLOAT4 and XMFLOAT4X4 data types to store the values.
3. I've got rid of global variables and have made camera* shared_ptr.

I still use DirectXMath library and SSE intrinsics. 
App works. Thank you so much for your answer.