# How to do this in Direct x 11?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directx-9

I am just wondering how I can do the following code from Direct X 9 in Direct X 11? I know the MatrixRotationAxis and TransformCoord in Direct X 11 only takes in 2 parameters so I am not sure if it will work the same as the code below.

```
 D3DXMATRIX pitchMatrix;
 D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&pitchMatrix, &right, pitch);
 D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&look, &look, &pitchMatrix); 
 D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&up, &up, &pitchMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing with DirectX version. It's about math libraries. After deprecation and stripping out D3DXMath from SDK we are forced to use DirectXMath or 3rd party math libraries instead.

See [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) for porting instructions.

Also, probably you will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18944995/1607442) useful.

*Edit:* Worth to add that DirectXMath has specific alignment requirements. Make sure you don't overlook that (see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437516/access-violation-and-strange-behavior-of-visual-studio/22451748#22451748))

*Edit2*: Specifically, [`XMMatrixRotationAxis`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixrotationaxis%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts 2 parameters, because it returns result. With [`D3DXMatrixRotationAxis`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you expect result in third argument. See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Hope this helps! Happy porting!